# Неуникальный ключ к TDictionary

Tags: delphi, поиск, generics, словари, биоинформатика

Для обработки карты точечных мутаций исторически использовался следующий класс:

```
type
  TVCFRec = record
      id, alt, filter, info:string;
      qual: double;
      <...>
  end;
  TVCFRef = TDictionary<string,TVCFRec>; // #reference
  TVCFPos = TDictionary<integer,TVCFRef>; // #position

  TVCFFile = class (TDictionary<string,TVCFPos>) // #chr
  private
       <...>
  protected
       <...>
  public
       <...>
  end;
```

Фактически, это трёхуровневый TDictionary, который забирает сырые данные с прибора/приборов/архивов и раскладывает всё по полочкам, обеспечивая быстрый доступ (очень быстрый, выбор в пользу TDictionary в свое время сделан из-за скорости и удобства работы), поиск, запись, обработку, даже вывод на 3d-принтер :)
Его трёхуровневость позволяет быстро найти данные по вектору {хромосома, позиция в хромосоме, тип замены в референсе} (chr, position, reference)
До сих пор для одного пациента вектора всегда были уникальны, т.е. сочетание всех трёх переменных в векторе могло встретиться у одного человека только один раз.
Теперь появились данные о новых мутациях, плюс мы расширили свои возможности. Как итог, уникальность по третьему параметру потерялась, т.е. в данной позиции данной хромосомы могут быть разные референсные замены. **TVCFRef** теперь использовать невозможно, потому что ключ string в нём может быть неуникальным.
Переходить к БД, к другому подходу и т.п. не выйдет - многое завязано уже на подобный подход. Плодить четвёртый уровень - тоже не выход. Нужно допилить третий уровень класса так, что он позволял ссылаться на несколько вариантов мутации по одной той же позиции с одним и тем же референсом.
Мне приходит в голову только один вариант: определить TVCFRec таким образом:

```
type
  TVCFR = record
      id, alt, filter, info:string;
      qual: double;
      <...>
      end;
  TVCFRec = array of TVCFR;
```

То есть, если мутация неоднозначна, длина массива будет отлична от единицы и мы сможем работать со всеми мутациями путём перебора.
Решение не кажется мне до конца удачным. Может, есть альтернативы?

Comment: Дополнить ключ каким-нибудь значением (к примеру - сложить с любым параметром из TVCFRec), которое позволит "восстановить" уникальность нельзя?

Comment: В этом случае поиск станет невозможным. Да, наверное, можно просто первый char ключа выделить под вариабельность (тупо: 0, 1, 2, 3... вряд ли количество мутаций в одной позиции в ближайшее время достигнет 255). Правда, поиск будет труднее. Надо прикинуть, что выигрышнее, моя придумка или Ваша. Спасибо!

Comment: Нет, увы, поиск по референсу в этом случае становится очень ресурсоемким

Comment: Тогда, учитывая требование `позволял ссылаться на несколько вариантов мутации по одной той же позиции с одним и тем же референсом` - это действительно либо массив, либо TList, либо Dictionary внутри существующего словаря. В любом случае - это +1 уровень вложенности.

Comment: возможно имеет смысл создать класс-наследник словаря, добавить туда свойства, возможно, индексные, чтобы обеспечить минимальные изменения вызывающего кода.

Comment: Это-то как раз не проблема. Проблема в том, что сложно на данном этапе предугадать, во что выльется затем модернизация. Новый слой TDictionary - это O(n). Массив или TList - пока меньше, но, я не уверен, что так будет при любом объеме данных. Вот и "чешу репу" :)

Comment: Я правильно понял, вы хотите по одному ключу хранить несколько значений? Видимо нужно модифицировать стандартный словарь (в теории это не сложно). Как вариант (если таких записей ничтожно мало), то внутри TVCFRec = record можно делать некий флаг, который укажет, что это не единичная запись, а ссылка на массив (через case record). Пожертвуем одним битом на record и некоторым временем на декодировние.

Comment: Это "дороже", нежели  массив из TVCFRec: во-первых, больше действий на проверку и обработку, во-вторых, придётся модифицировать почти все методы обработки данных мутаций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу на собственный вопрос по причине того, что для биоинформатиков схожая задача может встречаться всё чаще и чаще.

Мы постарались промоделировать ситуацию на ближайшие годы (улучшение приборов, вплоть до отхода от NGS, увеличения количества отслеживаемых мутаций, повышение интереса к анализу собственного генома). В критическом варианте у нас получилось, что неуникальность ключа появляется в 26.2% случаев. Это предположительно наблюдаемый максимум. Исходя из этого, логичнее всего не вводить 4й уровень TDictionary, а использовать массив, как предполагалось.

Всё же вопрос хочу оставить открытым на случай нахождения более оптимального решения.