# Импорт данных секвенирования и обработка SAM-файлов в TDictionary

Tags: delphi, generics, биоинформатика

До сих пор, работая непосредственно с SAM-файлами, мы использовали массивы. Сейчас хотим перейти на TDictionary, поскольку он гораздо удобнее в плане поиска. Возникают вопросы:
1. Иерархия словаря. Как я вижу себе структуру, которая была бы удобна для поиска:

```
type
DataType = record
  name,qual, info, seq:string;
  data:array[1..30] of double;
  paired, structured:boolean;
  ref:integer;
end;

TData3 = TDictionary<string, DataType>;  // по имени референса
TData2 = TDictionary<integer, TData3>; // по позиции внутри хромосомы
TData1 = TDictionary<integer, TData2>; по хромосомам

var
  dd: TData1;
```

тогда я могу достаточно быстро пробежаться вниз по дереву chr->pos->ref и все записи будут уникальны. А для работы с переменной dd создаю свой класс, где будут все рутины.
Прав ли я, предполагая такую структуру?

2. Как правило, в большинстве биоинформатических утилит для обозначения хромосом используются строковый тип ['1'...'22','X','Y','MT']. Формально, я могу TData1 определить как

> ```
> type 
>    TData1 = TDictionary <string, TData2>; по хромосомам
> ```

но боюсь, что выигрывая в удобстве, потеряю в скорости поиска. Так ли это?

Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вначале отвечу на второй вопрос. По опыту, разницы в скорости не наблюдается. Более того, удобнее оставлять сведения о хромосоме именно в текстовом виде, так как порой приходится иметь дело со сложными именованиями хромосом, а не все утилиты поддерживают таблицу номерного соответствия.
Более того, я предлагаю совместить первый и второй уровень вашего словаря, сделав ключом сразу полную координату {chr, pos} в виде строки формируя её либо так Key:= chr + ',' + IntToStr(pos), либо так Key:= chr + #9 + IntToStr(pos). Первый случай удобен для экспорта в Excel или BED, второй - для SAM/BAM. Скорость поиска возрастёт, неудобств при формировании ключа - минимум.
И ещё, отдельный класс создавать, на мой взгляд, не нужно. Наследуйте непосредственно TDictionary, так будет гораздо удобнее.
Суммируя всё вышенаписанное, предлагаю сделать так:

```
type
DataType = record
  name,qual, info, seq:string;
  data:array[1..30] of double;
  paired, structured:boolean;
  ref:integer;
end;

TData3 = TDictionary<string, DataType>;  // по имени референса
TData1 = class(TDictionary<string, TData3>); по хромосоме и позиции, ключ строится, как описано выше
    // переменные и методы класса, к данным первого уровня удобно обращаться без разъименования.
   end;
```

И встречный вопрос: ключ в TData3 и name в DataType у вас не одно и то же?

Comment: P.S. Мы используем схожую структуру для обработки соматики: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747957/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-%d0%ba-tdictionary

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. И спасибо за подсказку, как убрать уровень древа - так действительно будет быстрее!!! И да, ключ и name - одно и то же. Вы предлагаете убрать name из DataType? Но тогда, работая с переменной этого типа, я не буду иметь под рукой name.

Comment: По вышей ссылке: а почему вы не используете тот же подход? У вас ведь хромосома и позиции находятся на разных уровнях дерева.

Comment: Очень часто приходится копировать данные сразу по всей хромосоме. Поэтому вынуждены были использовать раздельные ключи

Comment: name вы можете скопировать из ключа. По опыту работы с SAM он может достигать 127 байтов, это сколько лишнего вы будете таскать с собой. Плюс, при записи в файл либо вы будете писать лишние данные, либо отдельно придётся убирать дубликаты при записи в файл/поток.