# Можно ли данные в дереве TDictionary писать в файл, как массив?

Tags: delphi, generics

Вопрос, непосредственно связанный с моим предыдущим [Импорт данных секвенирования и обработка SAM-файлов в TDictionary](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750068/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-sam-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-tdictionary)

Ранее, когда мы держали данные для обработки в массиве записей, мы просто создавали типовой файл и сбрасывали данные (а затем архивировали в ZIP, хорошо сжималось):

```
type
  data = record
   <...>
   end;
var
  f: file of data;
  d: array of data;
```

Теперь, если мы будем использовать структуру

```
type
DataType = record
  name,qual, info, seq:string;
  data:array[1..30] of double;
  paired, structured:boolean;
  ref:integer;
end;

TData3 = TDictionary<string, DataType>;  
TData1 = class(TDictionary<string, TData3>);
   end;
```

Можно ли использовать тот же подход, что и раньше, т.е. сбрасывать данные в типовой файл? Или необходимо использовать FileStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно конвертировать в массив, но, подозреваю, что не нужно. Особенно, если вы планируете делать это лишь для записи. Гораздо проще работать с потоками. Могу привести пример, как это реализовано у нас в базовом классе:

```
  TVCFFile = class (TDictionary<string,TVCFPos>) //
  private
    <...>
    procedure SaveToStream(stream: TStream);
  protected
    <...>
  public
   <...>
    procedure SaveToZip(const AFileName: string); override;
    procedure SaveToFile(const AFileName: string); override;
  end;


procedure TVCFFile.SaveToStream(stream: TStream);
var
  posi: System.Generics.Collections.TPair<string, TVCFRec>;
  pair:System.Generics.Collections.TPair<integer,TVCFRef>;
  third:System.Generics.Collections.TPair<string,TVCFPos>;
  i: Integer;
  writer: TWriter;
begin
  writer := TWriter.Create(stream, 4096);
  try
    writer.WriteListBegin;
    for third in Self do
     begin
      writer.WriteString(third.Key);
      writer.WriteListBegin;
      for pair in third.Value do
        begin
           writer.WriteInteger(pair.Key);
           writer.WriteListBegin;
           for posi in pair.Value do
             begin
                writer.WriteString(posi.Key);
                writer.WriteDouble(posi.Value.qual);
                writer.WriteString(posi.Value.alt);
                writer.WriteString(posi.Value.filter);
                writer.WriteString(posi.Value.info);
             end;
           writer.WriteListEnd;
        end;
      writer.WriteListEnd;
     end;
    writer.WriteListEnd;
  finally
    writer.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TVCFFile.SaveToZip(const AFileName: string);
var
  stream: TStream;
  zipFile: TZipFile;
begin
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    SaveToStream(stream);
    stream.Position := 0;
    zipFile := TZipFile.Create;
    try
      zipFile.Open(AFileName, zmWrite);
      zipFile.Add(stream, 'bigdata.tvb');
      zipFile.Close;
    finally
      zipFile.Free;
    end;
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TVCFFile.SaveToFile(const AFileName: string);
var
  stream: TStream;
begin
  stream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmCreate);
  try
    SaveToStream(stream);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Можно просто записать в файл, можно сразу в ZIP-файл, скорость записи и считывания достаточно велика (для загрузки есть аналогичные методы, строите их от обратного). Плюс, понадобятся методы для загрузки из SAM, записи в него же, возможно, понадобится поддержка BED, VCF и прочее, а, может, вы всё это сделаете в других классах.

Comment: Ух, спасибо, опять вы меня выручаете :)