# Как правильно сохранить большой массив данных в ZIP с использованием TZipFile?

Tags: delphi, zip, словари, биоинформатика

Есть класс TPosDict для хранения данных, связанных с обработкой геномов, - наследник TDictionary, с добавленными методами SaveToFile, SaveToZIPFile. SaveToFile работает нормально, но файл на диске получается великоват, ZIP'ом такой файл жмётся замечательно. При попытке же жать его "на лету" с использованием TZipFile вылетает ошибка "`Out of memory while expanding memory stream`", несмотря на то, что памяти - до чёртиков, хватило бы ещё на 20 таких потоков. Код:

```
type
  PosIndex = packed record
     chr, pos:integer;
  end;
  PosIndexData = record
    gname, rname, promoter: string;
    count:array[0..NOfTissues-1] of word;
  end;

TPosDict = class (TDictionary<PosIndex, PosIndexData>)
 private
   procedure SaveToStream(stream: TStream);
   procedure LoadFromStream(stream: TStream);
 public
   procedure SaveToFile(filename:string);
   procedure LoadFromFile(filename:string);
   procedure LoadFromZip(AFileName, InnerName: string);
   procedure SaveToZip(AFileName, InnerName: string);
end;


procedure TPosDict.SaveToStream(stream: TStream);
var
  writer: TWriter;
  ps:PosIndex;
  pid:PosIndexData;
begin
  writer := TWriter.Create(stream, 4096);
  try
    writer.WriteListBegin;
    for ps in Self.Keys do
      begin
        pid:=Items[ps];
        writer.WriteInteger(ps.chr);
        writer.WriteInteger(ps.pos);
        writer.WriteString(pid.gname);
        writer.WriteString(pid.rname);
        writer.WriteString(pid.promoter);
        writer.Write(pid.count,sizeof(pid.count));
      end;
    writer.WriteListEnd;
  finally
    writer.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TPosDict.SaveToZip(AFileName, InnerName: string);
var
  stream: TStream;
  zipFile: TZipFile;
begin
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    SaveToStream(stream);
    stream.Position := 0;
    zipFile := TZipFile.Create;
    try
      zipFile.Open(AFileName, zmWrite);
      zipFile.Add(stream, InnerName);
      zipFile.Close;
    finally
      zipFile.Free;
    end;
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Понятно, что TMemoryStream не может вместить такое количество данных (словарь может легко достигать и 4, и 6 Гигабайт). Значит, надо как-то сбрасывать их по ходу заполнения, но вот как - придумать не могу. Во-первых, надо как-то сегментировать словарь при записи, но как? Во-вторых, мне не совсем понятно, последовательные вызовы zipFile.Add добавят данные или перезапишут их?

Comment: Если памяти достаточно, то скорее всего вы скомпилировали приложение как 32-х битное, которому доступно не более 2-4 Гб памяти. Чтобы использовать всю доступную память, приложение надо собирать как 64-х битное.

Comment: @zed Нет, даже в 64-битном будет ошибка: TMemoryStream это какая-то "заглушка", сам не раз натыкался на подобное. Разгребусь с неотложкой, которая внезапно упала, попробую ответить.

Comment: Захотелось разобраться, почему это происходит. Разобрался :) Так что вы можете продолжать использовать свои методы неизменными, если повторите мои экзерсизы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784534/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы воспользовались моим ответом в теме [Можно ли данные в дереве TDictionary писать в файл, как массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750156/) и пытаетесь писать любые библиотеки в ZIP? Увы, TMemoryStream в Delphi почему-то не приспособлен под большие данные, даже в 64-битном режиме (с другой стороны, подобное использование памяти расточительно).

Сегментировать, на мой взгляд, тут бессмысленно: будет биться словарь. Разве что вы захотите поделить свою библиотеку, например, по хромосомам, но и тут вы рискуете наткнуться на ту же ошибку при очень большом объёме данных.
Я предлагаю вам в данном случае забыть про TZipFile и работать через TZCompressionStream.
Плюсы подобного решения: исчезнет ошибка нехватки памяти, уменьшатся скачки её использования, увеличится скорость (пусть и не очень заметно). Минусы: в один ZIP-файл вы сможете писать одну библиотеку, придётся ручками реализовать методы а ля TWriter.WriteString и им подобные (но за счёт этого скорость и увеличится).

Реализация (я покажу подход, - дальше сами):

```
procedure TPosDict.SaveToZip(AFileName: string);
var
  stream:TZCompressionStream;
  ff:TFileStream;
  ps:PosIndex;
  pid:PosIndexData;
  l:integer;
begin
   ff:=TFileStream.Create(AFileName,fmCreate);
   stream:=TZCompressionStream.Create(ff);
    for ps in Self.Keys do
      begin
        pid:=Items[ps];
        stream.WriteBuffer(ps.chr,SizeOf(Integer)); // можете использовать даже Write, если уверены в своих действиях, это будет ещё немного быстрее
        stream.WriteBuffer(ps.pos,SizeOf(Integer));
        l:=length(pid.gname);
        stream.WriteBuffer(l,sizeof(integer));
        stream.WriteBuffer(pid.gname,SizeOf(pid.gname));

        И так далее... 

      end;
   stream.Free;
   ff.Free;
end;
```

LoadFromZIP - обращайте процесс

На самом деле, существует ещё куча всяких библиотек и компонентов, реализующих запись/считывание ZIP-файлов. Возможно, среди них есть лучший/более простой подход.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать. Другие компоненты не подскажете?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Скажу честно, другие просто не пробовал, а рекомендовать что-то, о чём ничего не знаю, - как-то язык не ворочается :)

Comment: По ответу: да, сработало. Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, а что мешает завернуть `TZCompressionStream` в `TWriter` или `TStreamWriter`?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Если я правильно вас понял, то не получится: всё равно вылетит с ошибкой при превышении 2 Гб.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Боюсь, скорости не добавится, а вот плясок с бубном - да. Впрочем, могу не понимать вашей идеи

Comment: Уже сам разобрался :) Да, вы правы. `TStreamWriter` это для записи только текста, он здесь не подойдет. А `TWriter` не подойдет потому, что его свойство `Position` типа `Longint` и по этому, он больше 2 ГБ не умеет.