# Невозможно выделить память более 2 Гб для класса TMemoryStream даже в 64-битном режиме

Tags: delphi, потоки-данных, x86-64

В Delphi, в том числе в последних версиях (могу проверить только до 10.1 Berlin, хотя негативные отзывы есть и о 10.2 Tokyo), класс TMemoryStream не может выделить под данные более 2 Гб даже при компиляции в 64-битном режиме. Попытки записать в поток большие объёмы приводят к ошибке `"Out of memory while expanding memory stream"`.

Можно ли решить эту проблему без создания собственного класса, реализующего поток в памяти?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте взглянем в определение класса **TMemoryStream** в файле System.Classes.pas:

```
  TMemoryStream = class(TCustomMemoryStream)
  private
    FCapacity: Longint;
    procedure SetCapacity(NewCapacity: Longint);
  protected
    function Realloc(var NewCapacity: Longint): Pointer; virtual;
    property Capacity: Longint read FCapacity write SetCapacity;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Clear;
    procedure LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
    procedure LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
    procedure SetSize(const NewSize: Int64); override;
    procedure SetSize(NewSize: Longint); override;
    function Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
    function Write(const Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint; override;
  end;
```

Сразу отмечаем, что для адресации памяти используются переменные типа longint, что, естественно, объясняет невозможность использования более 2 Гб. Более того, если взглянуть на методы Read (их два) непосредственного предка **TMemoryStream** - **TCustomMemoryStream**:

```
function TCustomMemoryStream.Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  if (FPosition >= 0) and (Count >= 0) then
  begin
    Result := FSize - FPosition;
    if Result > 0 then
    begin
      if Result > Count then Result := Count;
      Move((PByte(FMemory) + FPosition)^, Buffer, Result);
      Inc(FPosition, Result);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

function TCustomMemoryStream.Read(Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  if (FPosition >= 0) and (Count >= 0) then
  begin
    Result := FSize - FPosition;
    if Result > 0 then
    begin
      if Result > Count then Result := Count;

      Move((PByte(FMemory) + FPosition)^, Buffer[Offset], Result);
      Inc(FPosition, Result);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;
```

, то заметим, что результат может быть посчитан неправильно.

Поэтому решением было: заменить тип переменных внутри **TMemoryStream** на NativeInt и Int64, в том числе локальных переменных, а методы **TCustomMemoryStream**.Read переписать, например, так:

```
function TCustomMemoryStream.Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
var
  diff: Int64;
begin
  if (FPosition >= 0) and (Count >= 0) then
  begin
    diff := FSize - FPosition;
    if diff > 0 then
    begin
      if diff > Count then
        Result := Count
      else
        Result := diff;
      Move((PByte(FMemory) + FPosition)^, Buffer, Result);
      Inc(FPosition, Result);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

function TCustomMemoryStream.Read(Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint;
var
  diff: Int64;
begin
  if (FPosition >= 0) and (Count >= 0) then
  begin
    diff := FSize - FPosition;
    if diff > 0 then
    begin
      if diff > Count then
      Result := Count
      else Result := diff;

      Move((PByte(FMemory) + FPosition)^, Buffer[Offset], Result);
      Inc(FPosition, Result);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;
```

Это позволяет работать с объёмами памяти более 2 Гб (тестовый пример спокойно обработал 5-гигабайтный файл, полностью скопировав его в поток.

Для тех, кто захочет внести изменения у себя в System.Classes, напомню, что предварительно необходимо сохранить резервную копию этого файла - на всякий случай :)

**Update 1**

Для тех, кто по какой-то причине не хочет идти по предложенным выше вариантам, могу предложить класс [TSegmentedMemoryStream](http://www.voelker-hud.de/de/programmierung/komponenten/24-klasse-tsegmentedmemorystream.html) - он доступен для скачивания и работает (проверено!).

Comment: Да, оказывается они этот класс не обновляли со времён Delphi 6: [Bug in TMemoryStream?](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108116)

Comment: Не лучше ли написать своего наследника от `TCustomMemoryStream` вместо того, чтобы править системные библиотеки? Такой код не скомпилится правильно на машине другого разработчика (без предварительных танцев с бубном). Такой код не скомпилится правильно на другой версии Delphi.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci 1. TCustomMemoryStream всё равно пришлось править, разве что в наследнике заменять его методы. 2. У меня установлены компоненты, которые используют TMemoryStream, а исходников у них, увы, нет. 3. Насчёт другой версии Delphi - некорректно, мне пришли уже "спасибы" от владельцев Seattle, XE8, XE6 4. Я не разработчик, а прикладник, а для нас такие мелочи, как перенос, в общем-то, малоценны

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Хех! Я ж говорил, что крокодил - птичка, а не летает, потому что зелёный :) Это я к тому, что неправильно было, что TMemoryStream не ест больше 2 Гб. Сейчас буду проверять.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Ах, да еще 5. Причины всё равно надо было показать. Зато теперь любой желающий сможет реализовать то, что вы предлагаете, опираясь на знание ошибок. Ведь каждый делает так, как ему удобнее.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Исправил (Delphi Tokyo), данные записались!!!!

Answer (score 4):

В текущей версии Delphi (10.2.2), класс объявлен следующим образом:

```
TMemoryStream = class(TCustomMemoryStream)
  private
    FCapacity: NativeInt;
  protected
    procedure SetCapacity(NewCapacity: NativeInt); virtual;
    function Realloc(var NewCapacity: Longint): Pointer; virtual;
    property Capacity: NativeInt read FCapacity write SetCapacity;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Clear;
    procedure LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
    procedure LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
    procedure SetSize(const NewSize: Int64); override;
    procedure SetSize(NewSize: Longint); override;
    function Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
    function Write(const Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint; override;
  end;
```

Видно, что они кое-как попытались исправить проблему, но она ещё не до конца исправлена (например, функция `Realloc` всё ещё завязана на `LongInt`).

В квалити-центре есть несколько тикетов касательно TMemoryStream:

- (баг, отработан) [TCustomMemoryStream and TMemoryStream don't work with very large streams](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19094)
- (баг, не отработан) [TMemoryStream Realloc not support Int64 For greater than 2G](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19321)
- (новая фича, не отработан) [TMemoryStream does not support large (> 2 Gb) memory allocations](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16137)

Так что есть надежда, что они наконец сделают в `TMemoryStream` поддержку 64-х бит.

Comment: А что с методами Read у TCustomMemoryStream в 10.2.2? У меня, увы, нет возможности работать с 10.2.X

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Там всё ещё `LongInt`.

Comment: Это они только-только заметили, что у них класс ущербный? Видимо, потому, что биоинформатики к Delphi потянулись, а у нас данные огромные :) Кстати, как получить доступ в квалити-центр?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Надо зарегистрироваться вот тут: http://members.embarcadero.com/