# Получить нужные значения, при условии если они есть в базе данных

Tags: delphi, pascal

Есть база данных (в моем случае, просто текстовый файл), примерно в 70 тысяч строк.

Задача:
 - к примеру у нас есть почта testmail@mail.ru нужно сделать проверку на наличие данной почты а конкретно домена @mail.ru и получить **нужные значения**.
Пример одной из строк из нашей базы размером в 70 тысяч строк:
 **aport.ru;imap.mail.ru;993;true**

Дело в том, что доменов может быть несколько а прогонять каждую строчку через цикл, не вариант, так как таких разных почт может быть очень много и работать должно довольно быстро.

P.s варианты использовать построчное чтение не идёт, я думал возможно сделать как нибудь например, проверяем если указаная почта есть в базе данных, затем как то находим строчку и выводим значения:

```
 aport.ru;imap.mail.ru;993;true
 - imap domain: imap.mail.ru
 - port: 993
 - ssl: true
```

Comment: про оператор `like` в SQL слышали?

Comment: еще можно подстроку с конца. а если надо еще быстрее, то добавить новый столбец для домена, вписать туда значения верхнего домена из адреса серверов, сделать индекс, и уже искать по конкретному полю. зы: надеюсь точка с запятой у вас это разделитель столбцов просто был

Comment: А какая у вас БД? Не CSV файлик случайно?

Comment: @zed К примеру у меня обычный текстовый файл.
 База данных это к слову, (база чего либо).

Comment: @teran Дело в том что, я не использую SQL, база данных имелось ввиду, обычная база любого формата (в моём случае .txt)

Comment: Вы принципиально не хотите использовать нормальную БД (к примеру, SQLite) в которой ваша задача решается элементарно и эффективно?

Comment: @zed Да, дело в том что нужна многопоточная работа с imap серверами, по этому я думаю SQLite мне не подойдёт

Comment: Зря вы так думаете. Если вам подходит текстовый файл, то со SQLite ваша жизнь будет похожа на сказку :) При правильном использовании, конечно.

Comment: @zed Интересно, не могли бы вы подсказать, в какую сторону мне "копать"?

Comment: Если совсем нет опыта работы, то придётся начать [с изучения матчасти](http://www.sqlite.org/books.html). Есть серия статей на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149356/), есть различные статьи в блогах ([например тут](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2016/08/sqlite-v-delphi-bolshoj-obzor-i-litedac-v-primerax/)). Есть туториал в wiki [Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC).

Comment: У меня так же есть парочка примеров: [без использования компонентов](https://bitbucket.org/zedxxx/sdb_util/src/afdc040668d728f10f61eaf3ef861df753e5c965/src/u_BerkeleyDBVerifyCacheImplDirect.pas?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) и с [использованием ORM](https://bitbucket.org/zedxxx/sdb_util/src/afdc040668d728f10f61eaf3ef861df753e5c965/src/u_BerkeleyDBVerifyCacheImplORM.pas?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Comment: Если не хотите связываться с SQL то можете один раз, при загрузке программы, разобрать файл построчно и засунуть куда-нибудь в хэшированный словарь (правда его придётся написать самому, стандартный не подойдет вроде) в виде записи: адрес - остальная часть строки. После этого просто обращаетесь к нему с нужным адресом и получаете обратно нужную строку.

Comment: @Alekcvp чем стандартный то вдруг не подойдет? :)

Comment: Чудес на свете не бывает. База для оптимизации использует индексы , которые позволяют ускорить поиск параметров. 70 тыс строк это копейки для базы, это не 70 миллионов записей. (даже не 1 Мб) Либо вместо индексов также имеет место тупой перебор. Попробуйте все-таки построчно просмотреть записи, уверен займет максимум 2-3 секунды. Думаю в Вашем случае нужно провести реструктуризацию базы или попробовать создать индексы.  Третьего варианта не дано.

Comment: @teran, [по слухам](https://habrahabr.ru/post/282902/) он тормознутый. Хотя, как уже выше сказали, 70к записей - не миллион :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Словарь на 70 тысяч строк отлично справится со своей задачей.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TBaseRecord = record
    MailDomain: string;
    ServerName: string;
    ServerPort: string;
    SSL: string;
  constructor Create(BaseRecordStringsArray: TArray<string>);
  end;

var
  DomainsDict: TDictionary<string,TBaseRecord>;
  RecordString: string;
  RecordStringsArray: TArray<string>;
  NewRecord: TBaseRecord;

const
  OUTPUT_TEMPLATE =
    ' %s;%s;%s;%s' + sLineBreak +
    ' - imap domain: %1:s' + sLineBreak +
    ' - port: %s' + sLineBreak +
    ' - ssl: %s';

{ TBaseRecord }

constructor TBaseRecord.Create(BaseRecordStringsArray: TArray<string>);
begin
  if Length(BaseRecordStringsArray) < 4 then
    raise EArgumentException.Create('BaseRecordStringsArray has not enough elements.');
  MailDomain := BaseRecordStringsArray[0];
  ServerName := BaseRecordStringsArray[1];
  ServerPort := BaseRecordStringsArray[2];
  SSL := BaseRecordStringsArray[3];
end;

function GetDomainFromMail(Mail: string): string;
begin
  // достаем домен из почты: testmail@aport.ru -> aport.ru
  // поскольку поиск по словарю чуствителен к регистру, нужно домен перевести в такой же регистр как в базе
  Result := LowerCase(Mail.SubString(Mail.LastDelimiter('@') + 1)); // предположим, что это нижний регистр
end;

begin
  try
    DomainsDict := TDictionary<string,TBaseRecord>.Create;
    try
      with TStreamReader.Create('Файл_базы.txt') do
      try
        while not EndOfStream do
        begin
          RecordString := ReadLine;
          RecordStringsArray := RecordString.Split([';']);
          try
            NewRecord := TBaseRecord.Create(RecordStringsArray);
          except
            on E: EArgumentException do
              Continue; // можно сначала записать ошибку в лог или выдать сообщение
          end;
          DomainsDict.Add(NewRecord.MailDomain, NewRecord);
        end;
      finally
        Free;
      end;

      WriteLn('Domains count = ' + IntToStr(DomainsDict.Count));

      // попробуем найти нужную нам почту
      with DomainsDict.Items[GetDomainFromMail('testmail@aport.ru')] do
        WriteLn(Format(OUTPUT_TEMPLATE, [MailDomain, ServerName, ServerPort, SSL]));

      Writeln('');
      Writeln('Press Enter ...');
      ReadLn;
    finally
      DomainsDict.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

P.S. Delphi XE5

**UPD:**
Если варианты доменов могут повторяться, то в этом случае можно в словаре хранить массивы записей: `TDictionary<string,TArray<TBaseRecord>>` и немного поправить код.

Переменные:

```
var
  DomainsDict: TDictionary<string,TArray<TBaseRecord>>;
  i: Integer;
```

После создания новой записи, вместо `DomainsDict.Add(...)` пишем:

```
if DomainsDict.TryGetValue(NewRecord.MailDomain, RecordsArray) then
begin
  SetLength(RecordsArray, Length(RecordsArray) + 1);
  RecordsArray[Length(RecordsArray) - 1] := NewRecord;
  DomainsDict.Items[NewRecord.MailDomain] := RecordsArray;
end
else
begin
  SetLength(RecordsArray, 1);
  RecordsArray[0] := NewRecord;
  DomainsDict.Add(NewRecord.MailDomain, RecordsArray);
end;
```

Поиск по словарю заменяем на:

```
// попробуем найти нужную нам почту
Writeln('Searching ''testmail@aport.ru'':');
Writeln('');
if DomainsDict.TryGetValue(GetDomainFromMail('testmail@aport.ru'), RecordsArray) then
  for i := 0 to Length(RecordsArray) - 1 do
    with RecordsArray[i] do
      WriteLn(Format(OUTPUT_TEMPLATE, [MailDomain, ServerName, ServerPort, SSL]))
else
  Writeln('Nothing found :(');
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что, кроме "aport.ru;imap.mail.ru;993;true" есть еще "aport.ru;pop3.mail.ru;110;true" и т.п. Поэтому не стоит использовать метод Tdictionary.Add вот так просто, лучше вначале устроить проверку, например, с помощью TDictionary.ContainsKey. А так - нормальное решение, у нас в биоинформатике и миллионы записей легко ворочаются.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov про повторы доменов у автора в вопросе ничего нет, а так да, я с вами согласен. Только в таком случае словарь, наверное, не самое лучшее решение, ведь повторы ключей в словаре не допустимы. Что делать с записью, если ее ключ уже есть в словаре?

Comment: Если таких ключей предполагается немного, стоит придумать заплатку и обойти эту проблему. У нас была похожая проблема но уровень ключа был ниже: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747957/

Comment: Благодарю за ваш вариант, да, забыл указать что варианты могут повторяться как сказал @ViktorTomilov

Comment: @UltraCoder дополнил ответ вариантом учитывающим возможность повтора доменов

Comment: @kot-da-vinci огромное спасибо, это то что я искал!

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно

> доменов может быть несколько а прогонять каждую строчку через цикл, не вариант, так как таких разных почт может быть очень много и работать должно довольно быстро

то смотреть нужно в сторону алгоритма Ахо-Корасик (вроде как он чуть ли не самый быстрый)

Читать тут http://aho-corasick.narod.ru/
и вот тут http://rsdn.org/article/submit/HowToFindAMillion.xml

А вот готовой реализации я не знаю, так что если кто-то найдет, то обязательно напишите сюда.

Comment: Что значит "нет готовой реализации"? Вот, как минимум, одна :) https://pastebin.com/cRqnPZyC

Comment: Не забываем про теги " delphi pascal"?

Comment: Перевести на Object Pascal, при желании, - один вечер, это гораздо проще, чем разрабатывать самому.